# How to count number of times a JIRA issue has been in a specific Priority

Tags: jira, jql

To see how many issues have been in my `Critical` priority within the last month I am using this JIRA JQL:

```
priority was Critical during (startOfMonth(-1M), endOfMonth(-1M))
```

But I cannot figure out if it is possible to COUNT the number of times it has been in this exact priority (it can switch priority multiple times)?

Answer (score 2):

Like rorsach mentioned, you can't do this with JIRA out of the box.

There are several add-ons that can help though.

[Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) offers an _ aggregateExpression_ JQL function that allows you to count issues or to summarize a field across issues that match your JQL. So you probably don't even have to script your own JQL function although that is also an option.
[image]

The [sumUp](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.cps.sumUp/cloud/overview) add-on likely offers similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of search functionality is not possible out-of-the-box in JIRA. Don't forget that JQL doesn't really have anything in common with SQL apart from the syntax. It's just a fancy way of filtering JIRA issues, it doesn't support anything like aggregation.

However..

If you're running a Server instance of JIRA, there is an add-on (formerly known as a plug-in) that might be able to help: [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overviewScriptRunner). It allows you to write completely custom functions that you can insert into your JQL (project = "Angry Birds" and customfield_10100 = myFunction()).

It has been a long time since I've had to use it so I can't say for sure whether it will help you achieve your end result but definitely check it out.